# Plotly Treemap Returns Blank

Tags: plotly, plotly-python

please see the fast fully contained colab example
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1lzaw1AmYeJtrcPBxcPCZPyeiACvv4U1C?usp=sharing

input:

```
%%capture
!pip install --upgrade plotly
import pandas as pd 
final = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/firmai/random-assets-two/master/test/file.csv")
final.head()
final.dtypes
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np

typed = "In-sample"
fig = px.treemap(final, path=["Data","Acronym"], values=typed)

fig.show()
```

output:

[Blank]

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to plot too many items in the treemap.

- I've effectively reduced it to rows that are in top 50th quantile.  Very small items are arguably not relevant to this plot.
- additionally just filtering to values >= 0 resolves

#### >=0 rows

```
fig = px.treemap(
    final.loc[final[typed].ge(0)],
    path=["Data", "Acronym"],
    values=typed,
)
```

#### quantile approach

```
import pandas as pd

final = pd.read_csv(
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/firmai/random-assets-two/master/test/file.csv"
)
final.head()
final.dtypes
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np

typed = "In-sample"
fig = px.treemap(
    final.loc[pd.qcut(final[typed], q=4, labels=[0, 1, 2, 3]).ge(2)],
    path=["Data", "Acronym"],
    values=typed,
)

fig
```

[image]

Comment: Hey Rob, I think you are on to something, but -- I think it is rather that I have used negative values (and plolty unfortuntaly have no warning in place for that) -- if you are able to test that and edit your answer, then I can accept it. Thank you so much.

Comment: you are correct - I've added a snippet to answer that just filters rows that are >=0 and it works

Answer (score 0):

This issue might also be related to how you handle NaN as treemap will raise an error if a parent has NaN. I had this issue when filling NaN with ''. Was able to solve with `df.fillna('NaN')`